# Weblogic startup exception

Tags: java, myeclipse, weblogic8.x

I am using weblogic 8.1 with myeclipse 6.0.

When i am trying to run the weblogic server, it is asking for a config.xml in mydomain directory. I am trying to boot with the default configuration, but then it is throwing an exception:

```
Exception raised: 'weblogic.management.configuration.ConfigurationException: 
Passwords do not match, unable to generate default configuration, please try again.'
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the admin username and password you gave when you created the domain doesn't match what's in the config.xml.  Did you copy a config from somewhere else?  That's a mistake.  I'd try re-creating the domain and starting fresh.